# Determine CGRect values of CAShapeLayer class in UICollectionViewController / CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have created a swift file that adds several (CAShapeLayer) sublayers to display graphic elements. I have successfully added it to a UIViewController with the code below, however, I cannot figure out how to add it to a cell of a UICollectionViewController. Specifically which code to use and how to get the CGRect frame coordinates / how to query the actual width and height of the cell.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let width: CGFloat = 100.0
    let height: CGFloat = 100.0

    let chart = chordChart(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2 - width/2,
                                         y: self.view.frame.size.height/2 - height/2,
                                         width: width,
                                         height: height))

    self.view.addSubview(chart)
}
```

// Here is the beginning of the swift file referenced above (UiView - consisting of UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer variables) :

```
import UIKit

class chordChart: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        formatChordDisplay()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
```

Comment: Here is the beginning of the swift file (UiView - consisting of UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer variables) :